# Selecting individual elements on mouse click HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to implement selecting individual elements on the click of the mouse in a html page. When clicking, I want to be able to find which element I am clicking on. The end goal is to be able to place a marker on a webpage and then have that marker stay within proximity of that clicked element/marker, using coordinates to keep that marker in place as the screen resolution changes.

for eg:- if there is

```
<div id="div1">
    <Button id="button1"></Button>
    <Textarea id="textarea1"></Textarea id="">
</div>
```

on the click of mouse I just want one of the elements to be selected like either `<div>` or `<button>` or `<textarea>` (furthermore detecting a class/id) without using the `onclick` method. I tried finding solution everywhere, but nothing worked out.

Please find attached link to the jsfiddle with some html/css, feel free to use to help explain anything :- https://jsfiddle.net/code_Learner/qzzrmod3/11/

Let me know if there is any confusion of what I am trying to do and I can try and explain it more. Any advice/direction on how to start with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ¿So you don't want to use an onclick event?

Comment: how should the marker look like? can it be a glowing border on the selected element?

Comment: @Lixus Yes, I don't want to use an onclick event

Comment: @naXa it could be anything, I just want to select the element and get its id/class

Comment: They way I see to solve the problem, is attaching an onclick event to the whole body, and recover the element you clicked with a jQuery selector like `$(this)` but I can't think of any way of handling a click in a web page without onclick events.

Comment: You say:  "I am trying to implement selecting individual elements on the click of the mouse in a html page. When clicking, I want to be able to find which element I am clicking on." but you say you don't want to use an onclick event?  Why don't you want to use an onclick event when you're trying to do something when the user clicks?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It helped me to figure out some stuff!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function ( e ) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

Comment: no problem.  clearly still quite a bit of a way to go to get to your end goal. but good luck!

Comment: Does this work with onmousedown ?? I tried implementing it with onmousedown it didn't work.

Comment: it would be ```mousedown``` in what i suggested, not ```onmousedown```.

Answer (score 2):

You can use onmousedown event to capture mouse click event without implementing onclick. Please go through below link https://jsfiddle.net/jpavanaryan/qzzrmod3/14/

```
<script>
function whichElement(e)
{
var targ;
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }
    if (e.target) {
        targ=e.target;
    } else if (e.srcElement) {
        targ=e.srcElement;
    }
    var tname;
    tname = targ.tagName;
    alert("You clicked on a " + tname + " element.");
}

</script>


<body onmousedown="whichElement(event)">
    <div id="container">
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
        <p class="p"> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mauris nunc, eleifend sed lacus in, tristique pharetra augue. Nulla sagittis ultricies mi, id pharetra sem feugiat in. Curabitur justo risus, varius et gravida vitae, laoreet eget libero. Sed ut orci lobortis, gravida metus quis, sodales sapien.
        </p>
    <ul>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
       <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing.</li>
    </ul>
        <p class="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec mauris nunc, eleifend sed lacus in, tristique pharetra augue. Nulla sagittis ultricies mi, id pharetra sem feugiat in. Curabitur justo risus, varius et gravida vitae, laoreet eget libero. Sed ut orci lobortis, gravida metus quis, sodales sapien.</p>
    <hr>
      <form>
    <textarea>Comment...</textarea>
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you I wanted something similar to this. This will help me a lot.